# Authentication subdirectory access

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

How to restrict directory level access to only authenticated users? I need www.testpage.net/help to be accessible only for authenticated users + help folder contains only pure html files.
Can I do this?
Currently uses can log into www.testpage.net.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `web.config` file with the access list defined there.  So, in other words, in your `Help` directory, have a `web.config` file that contains something like:

```
....
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
....
```

Comment: I have created directory help and put there one file test.html. Also I have created web.config in help directory with <authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization> I can access help/test.html without any authentication.